# XSD how to select more than one enumeration value

Tags: xml, xsd

I'm very new with xml schemas.
I want to select more than one enumeration value but it doesnt work. I tried to add xs: list but that didn't work too.

Here is an extract from my xsd:

```
 <xs:element name="charakter">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:simpleContent>
                                    <xs:extension base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:attribute name="haltung" use="required">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                             <xs:enumeration value="hoher Pflegeaufwand"/>
                                                             <xs:enumeration value="ideal für Garten"/>
                                                             <xs:enumeration value="ideal für Wohnungshaltung"/>
                                                             <xs:enumeration value="hoher Bewegungsbedarf"/>
                                                        </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:attribute>
                                    </xs:extension>
                                </xs:simpleContent>
                            </xs:complexType>

                        </xs:element>
```

So how is it possible to select more than one value?
Thanx for your reply.

Comment: It would help if you'd show example XML that you would like to allow and disallow.

Comment: okay that would be:
<charakter haltung="hoher Pflegeaufwand, ideal für Wohnungshaltung"></charakter>

But this obviously doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Your desire to validate comma-separated strings in an attribute conflicts with `xs:list` requirement that its values be space-separated.

You might try using regular expressions to achieve your goal, but better would be to redesign your XML so that `haltung` is not an attribute but rather an element with child elements.

Comment: I'm gonna try this, thanx for your reply!

Comment: Regex or redesign XML?